# Using a navigation case causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I get navigation problem in JSF 2.2 + Primefaces 5.0 when I click whatever `commandlink` or `commandbutton`. It is ok without navigation.

example commmend-link

```
<h:commandLink value="Login" action="login" immediate="true"/>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/view/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>  
    ....
</navigation-rule>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>#{GuestPreferences.theme}</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>2147483647</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>No Cache Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>No Cache Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlett</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Faces Exception Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Faces Exception Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.cyc.java.web.common.BootStrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error/500.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Enviroment is

```
jboss 7.1.1
jsf-impl-2.2.0-m08.jar
jsf-api-2.2.0-m08.jar
primefaces 5.0.jar
omnifaces-1.7.jar
spring 3.1
```

StackTrace

```
[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() fo
r servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
at java.util.EventObject.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71) [jsf-api-2.2.0-m08.jar:2.2]
at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:75) [jsf-api-2.2.0-m08.jar:2.2]
at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:73) [jsf-api-2.2.0-m08.jar:2.2]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:371) [jsf-impl-2.2.0-m08.jar:2.2.0-m08-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:268) [jsf-impl-2.2.0-m08.jar:2.2.0-m08-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.0-m08.jar:2.2.0-m08-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:122) [jsf-impl-2.2.0-m08.jar:2.2.0-m08-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:181) [jsf-impl-2.2.0-m08.jar:2.2.0-m08-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:645) [jsf-api-2.2.0-m08.jar:2.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:56) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
```

Comment: can't you just put link in command button? and try change it to p:commandbutton

Comment: @user2377971 I already test it. It is the same problem.

Comment: Your stack trace is missing the `Caused By` bit

Answer (score -1):

If you have used jsf project using eclipse, remove jsf-impl-2.2.0-m08.jar and jsf-api-2.2.0-m08.jar , and run it.

Comment: There is no `jsf-impl` and `jsf-api` jar at `WEB-INF\lib` folder. I just put these jar file as the module of `JBoss 7.1.1`

Comment: Are you using eclipse? If you are using eclipse then directly you can select DYnamicWebProject and select JSF2 in configuration, and you can get option to download jsf files

Comment: If you follow the above steps no need to put jars in jboss. just remove and run